# Python invalid syntax with "with" statement

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

I am working on writing a simple python application for linux (maemo). However I am getting `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` on line 23: `with open(file,'w') as fileh:`

The code can be seen here: http://pastebin.com/MPxfrsAp

I can not figure out what is wrong with my code, I am new to python and the "with" statement. So, what is causing this code to error, and how can I fix it? Is it something wrong with the "with" statement?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: same problem on Python 3.6.8 on Oracle Linux 8 (supported til 2029)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Most likely, you are using an earlier version of Python that doesn't support the `with` statement.  Here's how to do the same thing without using `with`:

```
fileh = open(file, 'w')
try:
    # Do things with fileh here
finally:
    fileh.close()
```

Comment: This worked, thanks!
However now I am getting a problem with the open function, the file does not exist. I want it to create the file if it does not exist. How should I do that? (I was under the impression that the open function could create the file too)

Comment: @mrlanrat: show your code and the error message that led you to believe that the problem is a non-existent file

Comment: Well, the file does not exist (I know that), and the error i get is:
`fileh = open(file,'w')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~./appCounter'`

Comment: @mrlanrat, Python by default will create nonexistant files. The problem is the directory. `~./appCounter` is not a valid directory. Python doesn't autoexpand `~` like the shell does and you have a misplaced `.`.  You probably want to use the path `os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "appCounter")` or something like that.

Comment: Note that `with` was introduced in 2.5 requiring `from __future__ import with_statement` and by default in 2.6. In 2.4 and previous, `try`/`finally` is required to ensure a file gets closed.

Comment: It was a typo, I meant '~/.appCounter'
So, what is the correct way to create a file in python if it does not yet exist?

Comment: @mrlanrat, `open(filename, 'w')` does that. Did you read what I said about Python not automatically invoking the shell to expand ~?

Comment: I added "file = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'),file)" which made it work, thanks!