# process large text file in python

Tags: python, text-files

I have a very large file (3.8G) that is an extract of users from a system at my school.  I need to reprocess that file so that it just contains their ID and email address, comma separated.

I have very little experience with this and would like to use it as a learning exercise for Python.

The file has entries that look like this:

```
dn: uid=123456789012345,ou=Students,o=system.edu,o=system
LoginId: 0099886
mail: fflintstone@system.edu

dn: uid=543210987654321,ou=Students,o=system.edu,o=system
LoginId: 0083156
mail: brubble@system.edu
```

I am trying to get a file that looks like:

```
0099886,fflintstone@system.edu
0083156,brubble@system.edu
```

Any tips or code?

Comment: looks like something out of LDAP. My tip only the stuff you need from there ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That actually looks like an [LDIF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2849) file to me. The [python-ldap](http://www.python-ldap.org/doc/html/ldif.html) library has a pure-Python LDIF handling library that could help if your file possesses some of the nasty gotchas possible in LDIF, e.g. Base64-encoded values, entry folding, etc.

You could use it like so:

```
import csv
import ldif

class ParseRecords(ldif.LDIFParser):
   def __init__(self, csv_writer):
       self.csv_writer = csv_writer
   def handle(self, dn, entry):
       self.csv_writer.writerow([entry['LoginId'], entry['mail']])

with open('/path/to/large_file') as input, with open('output_file', 'wb') as output:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(output)
    csv_writer.writerow(['LoginId', 'Mail'])
    ParseRecords(input, csv_writer).parse()
```

---

**Edit**

So to extract from a live LDAP directory, using the [python-ldap](http://www.python-ldap.org/) library you would want to do something like this:

```
import csv
import ldap

con = ldap.initialize('ldap://server.fqdn.system.edu')
# if you're LDAP directory requires authentication
# con.bind_s(username, password)

try:
    with open('output_file', 'wb') as output:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(output)
        csv_writer.writerow(['LoginId', 'Mail'])

        for dn, attrs in con.search_s('ou=Students,o=system.edu,o=system', ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, attrlist = ['LoginId','mail']:
            csv_writer.writerow([attrs['LoginId'], attrs['mail']])
finally:
    # even if you don't have credentials, it's usually good to unbind
    con.unbind_s()
```

It's probably worthwhile reading through the [documentation for the ldap module](http://www.python-ldap.org/doc/html/ldap.html), especially the [example](http://www.python-ldap.org/doc/html/ldap.html#example).

Note that in the example above, I completely skipped supplying a filter, which you would probably want to do in production. A filter in LDAP is similar to the `WHERE` clause in a SQL statement; it restricts what objects are returned. [Microsoft actually has a good guide on LDAP filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The canonical reference for LDAP filters is [RFC 4515](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4515#page-2).

Similarly, if there are potentially several thousand entries even after applying an appropriate filter, you may need to look into the [LDAP paging control](http://www.python-ldap.org/doc/html/ldap-controls.html#ldap.controls.libldap.SimplePagedResultsControl), though using that would, again, make the example more complex. Hopefully that's enough to get you started, but if anything comes up, feel free to ask or open a new question.

Good luck.

Comment: Okay, this is very interesting to me. After I processed the file and transferred to my colleague, they asked if I could do this on a nightly basis. Can I use Python to query the LDAP directly and produce the CSV file with ID,MAIL?

Comment: Yes, although the API for LDAP is quite a bit different. I'll edit with naive example.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, especially the LDAP update! I'll give it a go and see what I can come up with.

Comment: +1 for going to LDAP - I assumed that Alistair didn't have access to it.  I wish I could give you another +1 for the links!

Comment: Okay, so I am getting an error: `with open('id-file.csv', 'wb') as output:
SyntaxError: invalid syntax` with the caret pointing to the letter n in the word `open`

Comment: @Alistair: Could [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2755849/python-invalid-syntax-with-with-statement) be your problem? What version of Python are you on?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that the structure of each entry will always be the same, just do something like this:

```
import csv

# Open the file
f = open("/path/to/large.file", "r")
# Create an output file
output_file = open("/desired/path/to/final/file", "w")

# Use the CSV module to make use of existing functionality.
final_file = csv.writer(output_file)

# Write the header row - can be skipped if headers not needed.
final_file.writerow(["LoginID","EmailAddress"])

# Set up our temporary cache for a user
current_user = []

# Iterate over the large file
# Note that we are avoiding loading the entire file into memory
for line in f:
    if line.startswith("LoginID"):
        current_user.append(line[9:].strip())
    # If more information is desired, simply add it to the conditions here
    # (additional elif's should do)
    # and add it to the current user.

    elif line.startswith("mail"):
        current_user.append(line[6:].strip())
        # Once you know you have reached the end of a user entry
        # write the row to the final file
        # and clear your temporary list.
        final_file.writerow(current_user)
        current_user = []

    # Skip lines that aren't interesting.
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for that. It worked and all the comments were very helpful.  I had to add a colon to the end of the following line: `if line.startswith("LoginID")`

Answer (score 1):

Again assuming your file is well-formed:

```
with open(inputfilename) as inputfile, with open(outputfilename) as outputfile:
    mail = loginid = ''
    for line in inputfile:
        line = inputfile.split(':')
        if line[0] not in ('LoginId', 'mail'):
            continue
        if line[0] == 'LoginId':
            loginid = line[1].strip()
        if line[0] == 'mail':
            mail = line[1].strip()
        if mail and loginid:
            output.write(loginid + ',' + mail + '\n')
            mail = loginid = ''
```

Essentially equivalent to the other methods.

Answer (score 0):

To open the file you'll want to use something like the `with` keyword to ensure it closes properly even if something goes wrong:

```
with open(<your_file>, "r") as f:
   # Do stuff
```

As for actually parsing out that information, I'd recommend building a dictionary of ID email pairs. You'll also need a variable for the uid and the email.

```
data = {}
uid = 0
email = ""
```

To actually parse through the file (the stuff run while your file is open) you can do something like this:

```
for line in f:
    if "uid=" in line:
        # Parse the user id out by grabbing the substring between the first = and ,
        uid = line[line.find("=")+1:line.find(",")]
    elif "mail:" in line:
        # Parse the email out by grabbing everything from the : to the end (removing the newline character)
        email = line[line.find(": ")+2:-1]
        # Given the formatting you've provided, this comes second so we can make an entry into the dict here
        data[uid] = email
```

Using the CSV writer (remember to import csv at the beginning of the file) we can output like this:

```
writer = csv.writer(<filename>)
writer.writerow("User, Email")
for id, mail in data.iteritems:
    writer.writerow(id + "," + mail)
```

Another option is to open the writer before the file, write the header, then read the lines from the file at the same time as writing to the CSV. This avoids dumping the information into memory, which might be highly desirable. So putting it all together we get

```
writer = csv.writer(<filename>)
writer.writerow("User, Email")
with open(<your_file>, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if "uid=" in line:
            # Parse the user id out by grabbing the substring between the first = and ,
            uid = line[line.find("=")+1:line.find(",")]
        elif "mail:" in line:
            # Parse the email out by grabbing everything from the : to the end (removing the newline character)
            email = line[line.find(": ")+2:-1]
            # Given the formatting you've provided, this comes second so we can make an entry into the dict here
            writer.writerow(iid + "," + email)
```

Comment: @Alistair No problem. I did just realize I was using the wrong commenting notation though. Should be `#` rather than `//`. Too much time with Java recently...